# Why one can't pass 'parent' and 'tag' arguments as kwargs to SubElement factory function of xml.etree.ElementTree?

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, elementtree, keyword-argument

I'm using Python 3.6.5. What works:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
root = Element("root")
SubElement(root, "sub")
```

what doesn't:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
root = Element("root")
SubElement(parent=root, tag="sub")
```

So the only difference is passing `parent` and `tag` as keyword arguments (with proper keywords, mind you). Also look at the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: SubElement() takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)
```

How on Earth there were **0 arguments given**?

A look at the source for `SubElement`: [lines 443:459](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py) hasn't struck me with any revelations. As you can see the two positional parameters of `SubElement` are indeed named `parent` and `tag`.

Are we to have second thoughts about validity of [this particular](https://gist.github.com/0x4D31/f0b633548d8e0cfb66ee3bea6a0deff9#clarify-function-calls-with-keyword-arguments) Raymond Hettinger's piece of advice?

Comment: What Python version are you using, and if 2.x, which encoding? (Note, that XML always needs unicode).

Comment: Added the Python version used. Encoding shouldn't be an issue at this stage (we're not dumping to file anything yet)

Comment: In Python 2.7, you _can_ pass 'parent' and 'tag' as keyword arguments.

Comment: When using lxml instead of ElementTree, there is a slightly different error message (both Python 2 and Python 3): "TypeError: SubElement() takes at least 2 positional arguments (0 given)".

Comment: Now that's illuminating. What could be the design reasons for enforcing using only positional arguments on users? Fear about the user making a typo? (Then the arguments would be gobbled up by `**extra`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of that behavior can be found at the end of [`ElementTree.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1653):

```
# Import the C accelerators
try:
    # Element is going to be shadowed by the C implementation. We need to keep
    # the Python version of it accessible for some "creative" by external code
    # (see tests)
    _Element_Py = Element

    # Element, SubElement, ParseError, TreeBuilder, XMLParser
    from _elementtree import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

The Python code you can read ([`def SubElement(parent, tag, attrib={}, **extra)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L443)) is NOT the one that will be used when you call `SubElement()` from your own code. Instead, a more efficient version, written in C and compiled for your OS, will be used. This ensure better performances of the library.

As a result, some syntaxic sugar usually available in Python (ability to choose between named arguments or positional ones) may not be available.